# python-syntax error with speech marks in brackets

Tags: python

I was testing my code when I had the python interpreter highlight the last speechmark in these lines

```
q=(w-273.15)
print(str(q)"is the speed of sound at")
```

Comment: You need either a comma or a plus sign between `str(q)` and the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
q=(w-273.15)
print("{} is the speed of sound at".format(q))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.6, we can get something close:

```
q = (w - 273.15)
print(f"{q} is the speed of sound at")
```

These are called f-strings. They allow Python expressions to be added in the braces.